# how to remove SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way I can change this code so I can remove the unchecked warning

```
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
// do some stuff then
// save keys in session
HttpServletRequest request = getThreadLocalRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute(uuid, keys);

// get keys from session sometime later
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<String> keys = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute(uuid);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. `session.getAttribute()` is type-unsafe.

You can create a wrapper method, so that you only have the `@SuppressWarnings` in one place:

```
public final class SessionUtils {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getSessionAttribute(HttpSession session, String name) {
        return (T) session.getAttribute(name);
    }
}
```

Then you can use, without warnings:

```
List<String> keys = SessionUtils.getAttribute(session, uuid);
```

Comment: +1 for nice use of the T parameter. I guess that <T> is read from the assigned variable, right?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to choose between:

- Warning for raw type
- Warning for unchecked conversion
- Annotation to remove warning for raw type
- Annotation to remove warning for unchecked conversion

The thing is that `getAttribute()` returns an `Object`, so the compiler does not know that that `Object` is an `ArrayList<String>`, so it's warning you that there will be problems in case that `Object` is not an `ArrayList<String>`.

You can de-parametrize `ArrayList` so it would accept a `List` of anything (so conversion is not needed, thus removing the warning for unchecked conversion), but then you get another warning for raw type.